# Splash screen does not work when self-contain the .jar

Tags: java, ant, javafx

I use a splash screen feature for the javafx appliction. I use javafx ant task to run in order the fx:jar, fx:signjar, fx:deploy to produce the jar file, the jnlp file, the html file and the nativeBundles including "image" and "exe". The splash runs well when packaged in .jar file by double-clicks.
However, when I double-click the exe file in the application image folder or the shortcut after the setup by running the .exe setup file, there is no splash screen. Why? The exe file does not run based on the jar file? Thanks for help.

Comment: How did you create exe? Witch tool did you use?

Comment: What is the working directory context of the exe and how does that related to the images or differ from the Jar?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I use the javafx ant task to deploy my javafx application. Here is the javafx ant task reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/javafx_ant_task_reference001.htm    there is option "nativeBundles"="all" to create exe and a setup exe file if you've installed Inno Setup. So all this is automatic. The splash image is included in jar file, which is also specified in MANIFEST file of jar. So there is splash image when run the jar by double-clicks.

Comment: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8087431 and https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8091654

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and tried many possibilities in my *fx:deploy* (like adding a *fx:jvmarg*, *fx:jvmuserarg* and *fx:splash* under *fx:info*) and in my INNO script, I also tried generating the exe through *javapackager* and even changing the image format to *png*, *jpg*, *bmp*, but nothing makes the SplashScreen appears when it is running from a self-contained exe package. So I created my own alternative that may help whoever finds the same problem.

Main Class:

```
            SplashScr splash = new SplashScr ();
            splash.setVisible(true);
            MainFrame mainFrame = new MainFrame();

            SwingWorker<Void, Void> worker = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {
                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                    return null;
                }

                protected void done() {
                    splash.setVisible(false);
                    mainFrame.setVisible(true);
                    splash.dispose();
                    mainFrame.startProcess(args);
                }
            };
            worker.execute();
```

Depending on how long your *MainFrame* takes to load, you can add more or less time in the *Thread.sleep(2000)* or even delete it, but it is important that this *sleep* is running inside a *SwingWorker* or else the *splash* may not appear.

SplashScr Class:

```
public class SplashScr extends JWindow {

  public SplashScr () {

    ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("SplashScreen.png"));
    int width = image.getIconWidth();
    int height = image.getIconHeight();
    getContentPane().add(new JLabel("", image, SwingConstants.CENTER));
    setSize(width, height);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
  }
}
```

I hope it was useful for whoever found the same issue.